# 'more seniority' or 'higher seniority'

Tags: word-choice

(1) As our employees acquire **more** seniority in our company, they will be eligible for promotion.

(2) As our employees acquire **higher** seniority in our company, they will be eligible for promotion.

Which word is correct: more or higher?

Comment: _Seniority_ means being older or of higher status, so _higher seniority_ looks like tautology. I would use _more_.

Comment: Yes version (1) with “more seniority” is the best alternative. I’d also expect to read seniority used alone as in, “As our employees acquire seniority in our company...”